# REST: huge collection response

Tags: http, rest, collections

We need to display all entities present in a collection, let's say all employees. Should we return response as -

1. a list of URLs of each employee or
2. list of URLs of each employee & employee data or
3. simply list of employee records.

My manager suggested returning only list of employee URLs and UI can fire another query to an api that accepts a list of employeeIDs to get all details of employees (like /employees/list).

I'd like to know what is the restful way of implementing this usecase?
I think supporting employees/list is in itself not restful.

I feel the URL for this usecase should be /employees?params
and URL to access each employee should be /employee.
/employees?full=y should return full details of all employees along with their /employee/ url so that UI can support crud operations on each employee.

Please let me the know the best practice or the restful solution in this case.

Comment: REST includes query params inside the url path itself (`@PathParam`). I think it would be better for you to make some test REST calls back and forth server and client, and you will get yourself a better visibility of what is that you really wish to do. What is your language of REST implementation ?

Comment: of course query params are part of URL, i never said they are not.

Comment: @sivatumma - lang is C. we just need to display all (eg:emp) records in a grid sorted by some column.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, "/employees" with params return a list of IDs and the detailed info, "/employee/${ID}" return the detailed info.
PS: you can only return part of the list, the first 1000 records for example

Comment: thanks! I agree that /employees should return details of each employee. However, with each employee record, should it return a url to each employee like /emplpoyee/{ID} or just ID? Of course, employee id url might just return the same detailed info. Which is more restful?

Comment: this is good. It is best if it returns `/emplpoyee/{ID}`. (As you said). I now understand. More secured is there should be an ssl. (https) access to your server.